# Chrome Debugger breaking on incorrect lines

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When using The google chrome debugger stops on lines that are below my breakpoints. Are there any common causes for mismatched debugging lines?

When running the below example the debugger stops on line 1=1, additionally it has no concept of the variable y. Its like the debugger is using an old in memory javascript to find the breakpoints and overlaying the results on a newer source file.

Example

```js
var x;
x=0;
debugger;
x=x+1;
var y=2;
1=1;
```

Comment: Are you using sourcemaps?

Comment: When I click "Run code snippet" I get {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 18,
  "colno": 1
}

Comment: When I put <script>
var x;
x=0;
debugger;
x=x+1;
var y=2;
y=1;
</script>
in a .html file (I replaced 1=1 with y=1) and then load the page locally in Chrome, it stops on the debugger line.  I *do* have this issue going on in a bigger project where it seems like the sourcemaps must be getting confused, but have yet to get to the bottom of it.